# MariaDB SQL Select Min Date and the corresponding value from multiple tables

Tags: sql, datetime, select, mariadb

I need to do a select within a MariaDB, where I have one row per customer and the earliest date out of three different tables with action datetime values.

Example Tables:

**Main Table**

| customer-id | Column_X |
| --- | --- |
| First | Things |
| Second | Things |

**Table One**

| customer-id | Date | Action |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | Date | Action 1-1 |
| Second | Date | Action 1-2 |

**Table Two**

| customer-id | Date | Action |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | Date | Action 2-1 |
| Second | Earliest Date (Table2) | Action 2-2 |

**Table Three**

| customer-id | Date | Action |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | Earliest Date (Table3) | Action 3-1 |
| Second | Date | Action 3-2 |

My aim is to have the earliest date out of the three columns in the other tables in one column within the select and have the corresponding action with it in another column.

So the resulting table should look something like this:

**Result**

| customer-id | Column_X | First_Action | Action |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | Things | Earliest Date (Table 3) | Action 3-1 |
| Second | Things | Earliest Date (Table 2) | Action 2-2 |

I just started working with SQL statments and therefore have basically no experience. Help would be much appreciated!

Many Greetings
Chris

Comment: Why have you listed 'Main Table'? Why isn't there a earliest table from 'Table 1' in the Result? Can you write the query for the result for a single table? If so use `UNION ALL` to get the result for the second table at the same time.

Comment: I have included the Main Table because I need the information from "Column_X". In the result no entry of the first table is in it, because there is no earlier entry for the example customers, than those, from table 2 and 3. The background is that there are three tables in which different customer actions are stored. I want to create a table with one row per customer in which the information from the Main_Table (Column_X) is in the table, the earliest date for the respective customer from the three tables and the corresponding action. I hope I was able to explain it sufficiently.

Comment: Yep. Clear. While the query is possible, I'd reconsider why you have 3 different tables. Maybe the identifying reason should be a column in a combined table.

Comment: Absolutely. However, I can't change anything in the structure of the database and the query must also affect all three tables, since it may well be that the respective earliest action is stored in each of the three tables.